# GitHub giving me 404 File not found

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, npm-build

I am trying to put my web application up on GitHub but I keep getting a `"404 File not found"`. Does anyone know what to do to fix this? Here is what I got:

Here are how my files are set up:

[image]

And I made a build file in my client folder as shown here:

[image]

I have a git repo named (my-GitHub-username).github.io which is the format GitHub needs your repo to be formatted when naming it so you can host your web application.

Link to GitHub project: https://github.com/rmera1026/rmera1026.github.io

Comment: I want to ask a question to better understanding. Are you planning to create github page which serve some frontend from Github repo? For example I have this repo configured by Github Actions, deploys [this frontend repo](https://github.com/fatihayyildiz/typescript-vue-todo) to this link [github.io link](https://fatihayyildiz.github.io/typescript-vue-todo/)

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I am trying to do. However, the only difference is that I also have a backend part of my project where I use a database with MongoDB and that is located in my api folder. This is the link to the project on GitHub so you can take a better look: https://github.com/rmera1026/rmera1026.github.io @FatihAyyildiz

Comment: Yea API part is another story. How I handled it, via Heroku or Netlify. You can deploy your api with DB at these kind of provider's platform. Hobby instances are free and Heroku have free postrgresql running on free stack (not sure about they have Mongo support). I will take a look to your repo soon but for instance this api runs at Heroku stack. you can check it out. It's same logic what Github Pages doing, it uses Github actions to deploy Heroku
Swagger UI: [Herokuapp](https://todo-postgres-api.herokuapp.com/swagger_new)
Repo URL: [Github](https://github.com/fatihayyildiz/nest-todo-api)